# Replacing special characters in a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace

i'm trying to unittest a python function, but it seems to not replace any of the chars inside the function. even though the function should be working?

error message:

```
E       AssertionError: assert 'TE/ST-' == 'AEOEAA_TE_ST_'
E         - æøå TE/ST-
E         + AEOEAA_TE_ST_
```

**function**

```
class Formatter(object):

    @classmethod
    def string(self, string):

        new_string = string.upper()


        # split cases
        new_string.replace(' ', '_')
        new_string.replace('-', '_')
        new_string.replace('/', '_')

        # chars
        new_string.replace('Ø', 'OE')
        new_string.replace('Å', 'AA')
        new_string.replace('Æ', 'AE')

        return new_string
```

**test**

```
def test_formatter():
    test = Formatter.string('æøå te/st-')
    assert test.decode('utf-8') == 'AEOEAA_TE_ST_'
```

Comment: In Python 2 always mark your unicode strings properly: `u'Ø'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str.replace` is not an in-place function, meaning when you call it, it *returns* a value that you must *assign back* to the original variable, otherwise the changes will not be seen. As an example, consider:

```
In [315]: string = 'æøå te/st-'.upper()
```

Now, call `.replace`:

```
In [316]: string.replace('Ø', 'OE')
Out[316]: 'ÆOEÅ TE/ST-'

In [317]: string
Out[317]: 'ÆØÅ TE/ST-'
```

No change. Try assigning it back now:

```
In [318]: string = string.replace('Ø', 'OE')

In [319]: string
Out[319]: 'ÆOEÅ TE/ST-'
```

---

As a faster alternative, consider the use of `str.translate`. If you're on python3, you can pass a dictionary mapping of replacements (you cannot do this on python2).

```
class Formatter(object):    
    @classmethod
    def string(self, strn):
        tab = dict.fromkeys(' -/', '_')
        tab.update({'Ø' : 'OE', 'Å' : 'AA', 'Æ' : 'AE'})

        return strn.upper().translate(str.maketrans(tab))
```

For python2, you could choose to stick with `str.replace`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'maketrans'

Comment: @PeterPik Yeah I realised you're on python2 and so I modified.

Comment: @PeterPik Also, changed the variable name to `strn` so it doesn't clash with the module name.

Comment: perfect i see maketrans need to inputs, not sure what the second needs to be in this case

Comment: @PeterPik Oh... sorry. I forgot that str.translate on python2 takes two arguments x, y - each being a string of equal length with x[i] to be replaced with y[i]. In your code, you want to replace one character with 2... so I guess this is no longer possible in python2. On python3, it accepts a dictionary mapping which is much easier to work with. Sorry about that! You can still use str.replace with the changes I advised.